# Doctrine2. Generating lifecycles

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, metadata, generator

Im using YAML for decription entity metadata. Like this:

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ doSome ]
    preUpdate: [ doSome ]
```

Generated entity class looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function doSome()
{
}
```

It is all works fine, but this annotation "@ORM" confusing me. Should not be like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function doSome()
{
}
```

**How do i get rid of @ORM annotations?**

Metafile named as table.orm.yml. May be this cause the problem? But i dont know, how do this another way. If i name file like table.dcm.yml, i have exception that metadata not found.

Comment: What is your workflow? Do you create the `Entity.orm.yml` mapping-file first and run `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` afterwards? Now you don't want to have the lifecycle-event annotations in your generated class or what's the problem ?

Comment: I have file "Entity.orm.yml" in "src\BundleName\Resource\config\doctrine" folder. After running the command "app/console doctrine:generate:entities" I had file Entity.php in src\BundleName\Entity. Thats all.

Comment: I want to, or both added annotations (@ORM/prePersist,@ORM/preUpdate), or they were not at all.

Comment: I'll look into that - maybe it can be quickly fixed by a simple PR. This edge-case (different events invoking the same callback function) may not be implemented into the command yet. You shouldn't care about that too much and focus on gettings things done for now. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove the annotation and the corresponding `use` statement after the class has been generated.

The command ...

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

... is just a little helper to create classes and/or getter/setter methods.

It isn't always *100%* accurate. You shouldn't bother about that too much. It's just a helper ...

You'll still need to write your callback functions yourself anyway.